# how to change format of substring in swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

I get a message from my response like "your bill is: 10.00"

But I need to show in bold the number and only that (everything after the ":"). I know I could use SubString, but don't understand exactly how to split text and correctly format it

my old test:

```
    self.disclaimerLabel.attributedText = String(format: my).htmlAttributedString(withBaseFont: Font.overlineRegular07.uiFont, boldFont: Font.overlineBold02.uiFont, baseColor: Color.blueyGreyTwo.uiColor, boldColor: Color.blueyGreyTwo.uiColor)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, to split the string and extract the number part or how to apply attributes to the string?

Comment: technically both, but I was at first trying to select text, then look for a solution for formatting

Comment: What about `split(separator: ":")` for instance or finding the index of the ":" and use a range, there are many options here, which one is best depends on your requirements. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use it at all, the code I added is a way in wich in this app they are formatting a text but it is good only if you get some info separately, now I get a full string from response and need to format in bold what is after ":"

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into char `:` and then you can change text attributes like :

```
var str = "your bill is: 10.00"

var splitArray = str.components(separatedBy: ":")

let normalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: splitArray[0] + ":")    
let boldText = splitArray[1]

let boldTextAtr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: boldText, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0) ])

normalText.append(boldTextAtr)

let labell = UILabel()
labell.attributedText = normalText
```

labell.attributedText will print what you exactly want

Comment: this way ":" is erased, is there a chance to keep it?

Comment: Edited @biggreentree . you can manually add ':' to end of the normalText[

Answer (score 0):

How was `my` built ? If from 2 parts, set attributes to each before joining.

If you get `my` as a whole, you can access substrings with

```
let parts = my.split(separator: ":")
```

parts[1] will be "your bill is"
parts[2] will be "10:00"

Answer (score 0):

The need to add styling to a single word or phrase is so common that it is worth having on hand a method to help you:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func apply(attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], to targetString: String) {
        let nsString = self.string as NSString
        let range = nsString.range(of: targetString)
        guard range.length != 0 else { return }
        self.addAttributes(attributes, range: range)
    }
}
```

So then your only problem is discovering the stretch of text that you want to apply the attributes to. If you don't know that it is `"10.00"` then, as you've been told, you can find out by splitting the string at the colon-plus-space.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is redundant inside a `NSMutableAttributedString` extension method. `Key` would suffice

Comment: @LeoDabus style is in the eye of the beholder.